# How to debug `datum` transformations and aggregations in Altair (Python)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, altair, vega

I tried to create some chart in Altair using a few aggregations and calculations. I got the chart drawn, but that what was displayed on the chart wasn't looking correct. I wondered if it is possible to look at the result `datum` to check calculations.

Answer (score 3):

After some search and help from my groupmate, it turned out that one can see the result `datum` object. You have to press on 3 dots in the upper right corner of the chart -> Open in Vega Editor -> Data Viewer tab (right bottom part of the screen) -> select `data_0` resource.

I thought it might be helpful for someone, cause I haven't managed to find this info on the internet.